# c# choosing between Int and string variable type

Tags: c#

I am thinking about what type is better for save a flight number.

That data is numeric but i want to know if is better to create that property like a string or int type.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: There is no one answer. It depends on what you're doing wtih this flight number. I'd preferably pick `string` as a flight number is usually something i wont do any mathematical operations with

Comment: Decide based on your requirements. Using strings might have pitfalls, though. Sometimes flight numbers are used in a fixed format like "0045", sometimes not (like "45"). Note that the strings "0045" and "45" are not equal although both represent the same flight number...

Comment: This is very general question, instead of thinking about the type first - think about what you would actually want to do with the flight number. If you're ever going to be doing arithmetic or `between` searches then you'll need a numerical type - if it's purely for storage and 1:1 identification then use a string.

Comment: thanks for the reply. good observation

Comment: @TimSchmelter Increment a flight number? If that's a requirement, then alright. But im not sure i've seen flight numbers ever incremented before after being picked. They may completely change, but incremented? not sure.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - in Tim's defence I'd take this scenario as entirely hypothetical anyway. Any time I've seen a flight number it's had non-numeric characters in it. You can't assume incremented ID's aren't appropriate.

Comment: Use object! best flexibity! You can do with it whatever you want to!

Comment: @DeeMac No need to defend anyone, we're just having a crack at this :). I think having non-numeric charecters in a flight number disqualifies an int anyway, doesn't it?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov yolo!

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov no, ofcourse not, but the question itself is just not answerable, because you dont know anything about the requirements and the application. So there is no way to give a proper, good answer. I was just laughing about the fact that everyone was posting answers

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: if you work for an airline  and you need to create the flight-number(btw, who create a flight-number at all?), it would be a viable option to store a unique value and derive the complete flight-number from it + some other infos like Airline call sign etc. You don't need to store the Airline call sign additionally in the number since it is a redundant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use an `int`.

You've just said "the data is numeric", and an `integer` is designed for this. No need to steer away from the fundamentals of what types are designed for.

I'd imagine for a unique identifier mathematical operations are irrelevant, so a `string` would suffice, but consider how these values will work with their database equivalents (auto-increment etc.). Plus, it won't hurt for the type to be the same as what it would be in the DB depending on how you plan to map it over to objects in code.

Answer (score 1):

Are you going to do any arithmetic operations with them?

if not... String!

Comment: What if the number needs to be incremented?

Comment: In my opinion it depends on if the number has to be created by you or if you just store it. If you have no control you should use string because tomorrow it could be "RUS-1234-LH". If you control it and it needs to be incremented you should store the value as `int` somewhere and output the number with it's appropriate format where it is displayed (f.e. "LH 1727" where LH is derived from the airline).

Comment: @TimSchmelter: if it's a flight number, it's more like a identifying name than an ordinal... even more, it's probably fixed length, so no need to worry about leading zeroes when showing the number.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my english.

I recomand you to use Int because you can do with int math calculations and if you want you can take the int variable and do:

> .tostring()

But if you will use String variable and you would like to do math calculation it will be harder than you should do:

> int.parse(string var)

Answer (score 0):

Choosing right data type is always a compromise between ease of use, effectiveness of storage, ease of maintainability and other. It is a decision that is based on many interrelated factors and sometimes there is no such thing as absolutely right solution.

---

There are some points you should consider:

1. What is the format of the flight number?
2. Does it consist of some parts or is it a simple value?
3. How will it be used(what operations should it support)?
4. Will it ever change?
5. Is it being used in computation extensive tasks or indexing?

---

As it has been already said there are far too many cases and circumstances to consider, but if you can answer at least those questions then you can consider following more or less not wrong recommendations:

1. If it is a complex value like "ADF1398" then `Int` is not an option at
   all.
2. If it is just a number like 1290 then `Int` is decent solution.
3. If you are not sure what is it and(or) will it ever change then use your
   own custom type:

   ```
   public class FlightNumber : IComparable, ISerializable ...
   {
        // ...
        public static FlightNumber Parse(String strToParse);
        public override String ToString()
        {   // .... }    
   }
   ```

The last one is the least rigid solution, that could be easily extended or modified.